# Meromorphic function that preserves the upper half-plane and the lower half plane must have only simple poles, all of them in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation, analytic-functions, meromorphic-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ be a meromorphic non-constant function such that preserves the upper half-plane and the lower half plane.
Show that all poles of $f$ are simple and lie in $\mathbb{R}$.

By continuity, I've already noticed that $f$ must preserve $\mathbb{R}$ but I don't know if this is useful at all or what else to do, so I would appreciate any hint. Thank you!

Comment: What is the superior half plane

Comment: If you google a term and it doesn't show up, you should probably explain what it is

Comment: The superior half plane is $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \vert Im(z) > 0 \}$

Comment: Upper half plane $= \{ z \in \mathbb{C}, \Im(z) > 0\}$. A pole of $f$ at $z=a$  maps neighborhoods $U$ of $a$ to neighborhoods $V=f(U)$ of $\infty$. What can you say of $f(U \cap \{\Im(z-a) > 0\})$ depending on the order $n$ of the pole ?

Comment: I'm sorry, my native language isn't english, but I meant the upper half-plane

Comment: Try first with $f(z) = \frac{C}{(z-a)^n}$. In general $f(z) = \frac{C}{(z-a)^n}(1+(z-a)g(z))$ with $g$ analytic. Also for the same reason, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$

Comment: I've been thinking but I still don't get it, I think I should see $Im(a)=0 $ but I don't see how to conclude it from that